# How can I set an if to check multiple value in C?

Tags: c, logic

For example I want to check the following:

```
if((sample.x == 260 || sample.x == 261) && (sample.y==178 ||sample.y==179 ||) )
{ ...
}
```

How can I put it in a simpler way?(It's a lot of OR that I have to put in the if condintion, should I make a function? or how can I say something like :

```
if(sample.x == 10 between 20)//Thats my objective here
```

Thanks!

I am programming in C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem when trying to write readable code. If the values naturally fall into ranges, you can do something like this

```
if ((x >= 10 && x < 20) && (y >= 30 && y < 40))
{
    ...
}
```

Sometimes the logic is more complicated. In this case, you can have a long expression inside your if statement, but this can be hard for other programmers (or you) to read. A technique I like is to break up the condition into a series of predicates and compute each on a separate line:

```
/* get the bool type for readability */
#include <stdbool.h>

bool x_in_range = (x >= 10 && x < 20) || (x >= 100 && x < 110);
bool y_in_range = (y >= 30 && y < 40) || (y >= 200 && y < 210);

if (x_in_range && y_in_range)
{
    ....
}
```

This can make complex logic easier to follow. Simple memoized expressions like this should be easy for the compiler to optimize and generate comparable code to putting everything inside the if statement.

Lastly, if the set of conditions that trigger your if statement are really complex, you might want to encode them into a table and then write a small engine to evaluate the variables in question against the data in the table. This is a data-driven approach. In your case, the table might include a set of acceptable ranges for the x and y variables. This table and its evaluation engine might best be factored out into a separate function.

Comment: The C language doesn't have 'bool'.

Comment: It does if you #include <stdbool.h>. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a macro for that.

```
// define macro between, you get X<=V && V<=Y
// X, Y are the limits, V is the variable you are evaluating
#define between(V, X, Y) ((X)<=(V) && (V)<=(Y))
```

this returns true if *variable V is between X and Y*, false otherwise.

Then you can use this as a normal function

```
if(between(sample.x, 10, 20) || between(sample.y, 30, 40)) {...}
```

More info about macros [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)

Comment: Beware that V is evaluated twice in the macro, so watch out for side effects in its evaluation.

Comment: aren't macros expanded during pre-compilation? it's not really evaluated in runtime. i think the only problem would be to forget it's a macro and try to use it as regular function, in wich case they will be missing the semicolon at the end of the statement.

Comment: Yes, macros are expanded during pre-compilation (preprocessing). But that expansion will copy whatever is passed in as V twice into the code, as the macro dictates. If V has a side-effect (`x++` or `fwrite(...)`, for instance), then the program might not behave as you were expecting. This is because you wrote `x++` or `fwrite(...)` once, but that code executes twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could just check a range instead of each individual value, for example:

```
if ((sample.x >= 10 && sample.x <= 20) && (sample.y >= 178 && sample.y <= 200))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that did the trick, I had something similar, but that's the correct form!